# Navigate to a tab screen from a bottom navigation bar screen on button click

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button that should redirect me to the second tab on my tab bar upon clicking it.

The thing is that the navigation in my app is a little bit complicated , i have a main menu which is my Navigation bar , and i navigate between the screens in my app , mainly through it , each screen posses an index , for instance , index (0) the first screen, is composed of a tab bar that is itself divided in two tabs. I need to be able to click on a button in screen index (2) and then be redirected to screen index (0) tab 2. The app's current behavior is to redirect me to tab 1, which is quite normal , since i've instructed my app to redirect me to my main nav bar page and gave it the index (0) , so it's going to logically take me to the first tab .

here's the function that i am calling in the onclick action :

```
 void redirectLinkNotif(BuildContext context) {
    if (localNotification!.topic == "QRQC_CREATION") {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return BottomNavBar(
              index: 0,
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return BottomNavBar(
              index: 4,
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Here's my tab bar page :

```
class MainQrqcScreenWithTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainQrqcScreenWithTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MainQrqcScreenWithTabState();
}

class MainQrqcScreenWithTabState extends State<MainQrqcScreenWithTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/deepnBg.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            )),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBar(
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        labelColor: Colors.black,
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                        tabs: <Widget>[
                          Tab(
                            text: 'Mes QRQC',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'Liste des QRQC',
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(children: [MyQrqc(), AllQrqcListView()]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my bottom nav bar (main page) :

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<BottomNavBar> createState() => _BottomNavBarState();

  int index;

  BottomNavBar({required this.index});
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  bool isClick = false;
  int changeActivePage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      //activeIndex = index;
      widget.index = index;
    });
    return index;
  }

  List<Widget> pages = [];
  final tabs = [
    "Mes Qrqc",
    "Profil",
    "Ajout Qrqc",
    "Notifications",
    "Liste des actions",
    "Liste des actions",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    pages = const [
      MainQrqcScreenWithTab(),
      UserProfile(),
      AddQrqcScreen(),
      ListNotifications(),
      ToDoScreen(),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig.init(context);

    const kPrimaryColor = Color(0xFF1C5E7D);
    const kPrimaryLightColor = Color(0xFF1393CE);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.075),
          child: CustomBaseAppBar(
            title: tabs[widget.index],
            callback: () {
              setState(() {
                changeActivePage(3);
              });
              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then(
                  (value) => LocalNotificationsViewModel().readNotifications());
            },
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: widget.index == 2
            ? Visibility(
                visible: false,
                child: BottomAppBar(
                  clipBehavior:
                      Clip.antiAlias, //bottom navigation bar on scaffold
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(), //shape of notch
                  notchMargin: 6.0,

                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [kPrimaryColor, kPrimaryLightColor],
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.topRight,
                          stops: [0.1, 0.8],
                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : BottomAppBar(
                clipBehavior:
                    Clip.antiAlias, //bottom navigation bar on scaffold
                color: Colors.transparent,
                shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(), //shape of notch
                notchMargin: 6.0,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [kPrimaryColor, kPrimaryLightColor],
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.topRight,
                        stops: [0.1, 0.8],
                        tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => changeActivePage(0),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 38.0),
                          child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () => changeActivePage(4),
                              color: Colors.white,
                              icon: Icon(Icons.view_list_outlined)),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 38.0),
                          child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () => changeActivePage(3),
                              color: Colors.white,
                              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications)),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () => changeActivePage(1),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            icon: Icon(Icons.person)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        body: pages[widget.index],
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: widget.index == 2
            ? Visibility(
                visible: false,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  backgroundColor: kPrimaryLightColor,
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: const Text("OK"),
                ),
              )
            : FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: kPrimaryLightColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  changeActivePage(2);
                },
                child: const Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i want to be able to be redirected to index 0 , in my nav bar , tab 2 , and i have no clue how to do so if you'd be willing to help i'd be grateful , happy coding .

Comment: i am also looking the same issues. Have you get it any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

We can navigate to the different pages using passing the initial index to pageContoller.

initialize the pageController

```
 var _pageController;
  var _selectedIndex;


  @override
  void initState() {
    _selectedIndex = widget.selectedIndex;
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _selectedIndex);
  
    print(_selectedIndex);
    if (_pageController.hasClients) {
      _pageController.jumpTo(double.parse(_selectedIndex.toString()));
      onPageChange(_selectedIndex);
      _onSelected(_selectedIndex);
    }

    super.initState();
  }
```